# Convert Json object with one filed(object type) into json array of objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I am new in C#. I need your help. I have json like this from Oracle:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "myname",
    "avatars":[
      {
        "id": 1
        "typeid": 500
      },
      {
        "id": 2
        "typeid": 600
      }
    ]    
  }
]
```

but if avatars array have only one row, Oracle returns avatars like:

```
"avatars":{
    "avatars_ROW":
      {
        "id": 1
        "typeid": 500
      }
}
```

Now avatars is a json object with one field _ROW, not json array.

In addition, I have other fields (arrays) like this: `"roles", "accounts"` ... .

In C# I have all lists like `List<avatar>`, `List<role>`...

My question:

How do I find all the fields in object, whose name of first field ends with "_ROW", and covert they from object with one field (object) to array of objects with one member?

Thanks.

P.s. I can't change Oracle's functions source code.

Comment: Well, you would write code for it. "avatars" will give you either an array or a dictionary. So you check if it returned a dictionary, and write code that turns that dictionary into an array as you want it.

Comment: thanks. how can i check dictionary or no ? sorry, i came from Delphi. there working with json being quite different

Comment: Could you explain in more detail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't change "desired format". Oracle's function return json for me. 
I Founded stupid solution, but it works :) 
 This is my function to correct json:

```
// fix _ROW  in "pretty-print :)"  json text
static private String FixJson(String json)
{
    const String cRowString = "_ROW\" : {";      //  _ROW" : {"
    const String cEmpArrInvalid = "\" : \"\\n  \""; //  " : "\  "
    const String cEmpArrNormaly = "\":[]";          //  ":[]

    var lines = json.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); // json-string to string array. delimiter = NewLine
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) // loop strings
    {
        var line = lines[i]; // current string

        // oracle return json array with count=0 as "blabla": "\ ". I need "blabla": []
        char[] charsToTrim = { ',' };
        if (line.TrimEnd(charsToTrim).EndsWith(cEmpArrInvalid)) // find jarray-value with 0 elements. fucking Oracle's function :)
        {
            lines[i] = line.Replace(cEmpArrInvalid, cEmpArrNormaly); // replace bad substring( "\  " ) on empty array( [] )
            continue; // next string
        }

        if (!line.Contains(cRowString)) continue; // if not bad-string  => next string

        lines[i - 1] = lines[i - 1].Replace("{", "["); // _ROW found => in prev string replace object's start ( { ) on array's start ( [ )
        var pStart = line.IndexOf("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCulture); // find start position of field ( " )

        var sFind = ""; // string to search for end of object = backspace*pStart + }
        for (var k = 0; k < pStart; k++)
            sFind = sFind + ' ';
        sFind = sFind + '}';

        lines[i] = "{"; // replace singl-row property "blablabla_ROW": {   on start of object ( { )

        for (var j = i + 1; j < lines.Count(); j++) // from next line, find end of object. and replace object's end on array's end
        {
            if (!lines[j].StartsWith(sFind)) continue;  // if not end of object then next string

            lines[j + 1] = lines[j + 1].Replace("}", "]"); // found ! replace object's end on array's end
            break; // break loop
        }
    }

    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines); // join string array into one string with newline-separator
}
```

but would like to solve this problem by means of the library json.net, not parse \ change lines.

I solved the problem. My function:

```
private static void FixJObj(JToken jt)
{

    if (jt.GetType() == typeof (JArray))
    {
        foreach (var item in (JArray) jt)
        {
            FixJObj(item);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (jt.GetType() != typeof(JObject)) return;

    var jo = (JObject) jt;

    foreach (var jField in jo) // loop in object fields
    {
        if (jField.Value.ToString() == "\n  ") // if field value = "\n "
        {
            jField.Value.Replace(new JArray()); // replace "\n " with empty array [] 
            continue;
        }

        if (  !jField.Value.Any()  ) continue;

        FixJObj(jField.Value); // fix cur obj field recursive

        var jFirstField = jField.Value.First; // get first field
        if ( jFirstField.GetType() != typeof(JProperty) ) continue; // if its property

        var jProp = ((JProperty)jFirstField);

        if ( !jProp.Name.EndsWith("_ROW") ) continue;

        jField.Value.Replace(new JArray { jProp.Value });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might have this completely wrong, but I think you need to wrap it before you serialize the data, if that is what you are doing.

So your need a List and In Account you would have a List when this is serialized to json, it should be in your desired format.

If you look at some restsharp examples with wrappers then I think this would help.

Comment: i can't change "desired format". Oracle's function return json for me.